# Webpack - Call external JS in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm looking to swap to webpack from systemJS. Most of the setup seems to be working besides getting one of my external scripts running again.

Previously with systemJS I had a setup where I would import an external .js script in my index.html.

In my angular service I could interact with that script by doing the following -

```
declare var ExternalCode: any;
.
.
.
ExternalCode.RunProcess(data, infomation);
```

In webpack I now have 3 files being exported and injected into my index.html - app.js, vendor.js and polyfills.js. In my vendor file I import the code like so,

```
import "./AppScripts/ExternalCode";
```

If I then look into vendor.js I see my ExternalCode wrapped like so,

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

   eval( EXTERNAL CODE IS ALL HERE );
})
```

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is how I now call my external code from the webpack vendor.js bundle in my service. Is there anyway to now import / run the code from within my angular 2 service?

I've also tried just importing the script again in the index.html file, but on the webpack-dev-server it will always throw a 404 from the existing path that use to work when I ran the project with IIS Express and SystemJS.

Comment: why won't to try `angular-cli` ? it will handle all the `webpack ceremony` for you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to make it work the same way as I previously had with SystemJS. In vendor.ts as mentioned above import the script so thats its included in the webpack-dev-server.

```
import "./externaljs/ExternalCode.js";
```

Instead of treating the import like it's in a relative location to index.html, just pass the full path like so -

```
<script src="./src/externaljs/ExternalCode.js"></script>
```